# Where can I see equivalent of obsolete function modules?

Tags: abap

There are many obsolete functions in ABAP such as `DOWNLOAD`. I do not want to use these obsolete functions.

Is there any link or any method that will show me what can I use instead of these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Usually you can find the information in the documentation of function module which is marked obsolete. For example, in the case of `WS_DOWNLOAD`.

[image: Function module documentation WS_DOWNLOAD]

It is:

[image: Performance assistant WS_DOWNLOAD]

In case of `DOWNLOAD` function module.

[image: Function module documentation DOWNLOAD]

It is:

[image: Performance assistant DOWNLOAD]